# Can we deduce that $f$ is a decreasing function with respect to $z$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f(x)$ be a real decreasing function with respect to $x$. Assume that $x=x(z)$ is also a real decreasing function with respect to $z$.

Then my **question** is: Can we deduce that $f$ is decreasing function with respect to $z$

Comment: Suppose both functions are differentiable, and look at the derivative.

Comment: No. $x(z)$ needs to be *increasing* instead of decreasing.

Comment: Actually not . $x(z)$ should be increasing.

Comment: The composition of two decreasing functions is increasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No $f(z)$ is increasing function. As $$\frac{d}{dz}f(x)=\frac{df(x)}{dx}\frac{dx}{dz}>0$$ Also you can look at this in the following manner for $z1<z2$, we have $x(z1)>x(z2)$ and so $f(z1)<f(z2)$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true, like stated in the comments, $z\mapsto x(z)$ needs to be **increasing**.

For a counterexample, look at $f(x)=\frac 1x$ which is decreasing, and $x(z)=\frac 1z$ which is also decreasing.

Then $f(x(z))=z$ which is increasing.